# Writing assemble language programs on linux

Tags: assembly

I just started writing assembly language programs on linux(ubuntu) and know for a fact that I have a Intel processor. nasm use Intel like syntax and gas(GNU assembler) uses AT&T like syntax. But obviously my processor cannot understand AT&T syntax. So I was wondering how this compiler actually works behind the scenes? Does it take the file and convert the assembly language back to Intel syntax and then run it on my processor. If so , how does it know what processor I actually have?(Giving this doubt a little more thought, even when I install gcc, I dont tell it the type of processor I am using. How does it figure it out then?)

Comment: Your compiler doesn't understand either syntax, that's why you need an assembler.

Comment: +1 The assembler just turn human readable code (intel syntax or AT&T) into machine code (binary).

Comment: The confusion is most likely coming from the fact that you interpret "intel" to mean something backed by intel when in reality it is just convention..

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It's an interesting (and potentially useful) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your processor cannot understand AT&T syntax or Intel syntax. That's why you need an assembler. The purpose of an assembler is to convert from some syntax into instructions that your CPU will understand. The assembler does have to be told what instruction set to generate, unless it supports only a single instruction set.

Comment: Okay. But I dont specify the instruction set anywhere. I simply run it using as and ld. How does it find out what instruction set to generate?

Comment: Intel and AT&T are not instruction sets but different syntaxes of Assembly.  You use an Assembler (in your case NASM) which understands Intel syntax.  You could use GAS to use the AT&T syntax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language

Comment: @user1611577: If you don't specify the instruction set, it uses the default instruction set for your installation. That's almost certainly x86 or x86_64 depending on whether your installation is 32-bit or 64-bit. Note that instruction set and instruction syntax are two completely different things. Instruction set is what instructions you can execute. Instruction syntax is how you specify which instructions to execute. (`as --version` will tell you.)